# convert base64 string to csv javascript giving blob error

Tags: javascript

- I am simply trying to convert a `base-64` string to `csv`. The file is in `CSV` format transmitted in `base-64 string`.
- I am implementing this in `Microsoft Office Excel Addins`
- Code [base-64-string](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nXwqjQAC87PboogUQU-AxqjuUKEAcGQn/view?usp=sharing)

```
// getting the base-64 string
  let base_64_string = [base-64-string];

  // decode the base-64 string 
  let csvContent = atob(base_64_string);

  // convert the decoded base-64 string to csv
  var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "data:application/octet-stream;base64"});
```

- Error

```
Compiled with problems:

WARNING in ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 310:17-21

export 'Blob' (imported as 'Blob') was not found in 'buffer' (possible exports: Buffer, INSPECT_MAX_BYTES, SlowBuffer, kMaxLength)
```

- Another method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370162/converting-json-to-csv-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is not the problem (as demonstrated by the code snippet below).

```js
// generate a base-64 encoded csv string
const base_64_string = btoa("a,b,c");

// decode the base-64 string 
const csvContent = atob(base_64_string);

// convert the decoded base-64 string to csv
const blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "data:application/octet-stream;base64"});

console.log(blob);
```

Comment: This works, but while writing the ```csv``` data to ```excel``` it gives the error as ```Uncaught TypeError: e.match is not a function```, using ```XLSX``` functions.